# Where is the best place to map from view model to domain model?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2, asp.net-mvc-3, automapper

Where is the best place to do mappings from view model to domain model?  By mappings I mean from my `EditGrantApplicationViewModel` to a `GrantApplication` object.

Lets say that I have the following action method (partial code):

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(EditGrantApplicationViewModel editGrantApplicationViewModel)
{
   if (!ModelState.IsValid)
   {
      return View("Create", editGrantApplicationViewModel);
   }

   return View("Index");
}
```

Do I need to pass `editGrantApplicationViewModel` to a service layer method and do the mappings in the method?

Comment: @Sergi - he means mapping values from ViewModels to Model Entites.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You should **not** place any of your mapping logic inside the service layer since it simply dosent belong there. The mapping logic should go inside your controller and nowhere else.

Why you might ask? Simple enough, by placing the mapping logic in your service layer, it needs to know about the ViewModels which the service layer NEVER EVER should be aware of - also it reduces the flexibility of the app that you place the mapping logic in there since you cant reuse the service layer without a lot of hacks.

Instead you should do something like:

```
// Web layer (Controller)
public ActionResult Add(AddPersonViewModel viewModel)
{
    service.AddPerson(viewModel.FirstName, viewModel.LastName)
    // some other stuff...
}

// Service layer
public void AddPerson(string firstName, string lastName)
{
    var person = new Person { FirstName = firstName, LastName = lastName };
    // some other stuff...
}
```

By doing like above, you make your service layer more flexible since it's not bound to a particular class and it's not aware of the existence of your viewmodel.

**UPDATE:**

To map your Entities returned from the service layer to ViewModels, you might want to take a look at [Automapper](http://automapper.codeplex.com/) or [Value Injecter](http://valueinjecter.codeplex.com/).

Comment: I'd be interested in what if I have a fairly complex view model, which I would like to map to domain model? I mean not just firstname and lastname, but let's say 6 more properties. I wouldn't like to have service methods takint 6 parameters, nor would I like to introduce a THIRD class (after the domain model and view model) which represents basically the same thing.

Comment: Zoltan's question is the same question I have. I would want to pass objects and from the web layer to the service layer and not have to create an additional set of objects.

Answer (score 4):

Use [AutoMapper](http://automapper.codeplex.com) or similar framework directly in your controller.

[Here is an introduction](http://www.bengtbe.com/blog/post/2009/04/14/Using-AutoMapper-to-map-view-models-in-ASPNET-MVC.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

do it in your **WebUI** layer but **don't do it the controller** instead call your custom mapper/builder interface/class in there

**sample**: http://prodinner.codeplex.com

Answer (score 0):

I would personally never pass a view model to the service layer.  If you go down that route your service ends up having direct knowledge about what is displayed on the view.  This would cause changes in your viewmodel to cause changes in your service layer.

For example:
Let's say you decided to add a SelectList to your view model for reason for grant edit.

```
public class EditGrantApplicationViewModel
{
   //...
   public SelectList ReasonForEdit {get;set;}
   //...
}
```

This could be a perfectly valid requirement, but ask yourself does having a SelectList pass to the Service Layer make sense?  A select list is more of a UI domain and doesn't really mean anything to the service layer.  The service layer only cares about the reason not the select list.

I would take your view model, digest the information needed and then pass that unit to your service layer.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(EditGrantApplicationViewModel editGrantApplicationViewModel)
{
   if (!ModelState.IsValid)
   {
      return View("Create", editGrantApplicationViewModel);
   }

   GrantApplication grantApplication = new GrantApplication();
   grantApplication. // other fields.
   grantApplication.Reason = editGrantApplicationViewModel.ReasonForEdit.SelectedValue;
   grantApplication. // other fields.
   _someService.EditApplication(grantApplication);

   return View("Index");
}
```

If you haven't looked yet check out [AutoMapper](http://automapper.codeplex.com/) as it can help in doing between view model's, dto's and other classes.

Comment: @Mark: I spoke to a guy a while back and he said that your servcice layer must do everything, including the mappings, that is why I asked where the mapping should take place.  So I guess then that the action method is the best place?

Comment: @Mark: I do use AutoMapper, but the thing that I don't like about it (it's probably due to lack of knowledge) is when I have a FirstName property in both objects, and the source FirstName is empty and the target FirstName has "Brendan" then after the mapping the target FirstName is empty.  I hope this makes sense?

Comment: @Brendan, As for the service layer, it depends if you are doing N-Tier where the service layer is transferring DTO's across the wire you would use AutoMapper in that location as well.  Also, think of it this way as well, say you wanted to change the SelectList to a radio button list that shouldn't cause the service layer to change.

Comment: @Brendan, that sounds strange, not sure how that would happen.  Usually you go from one type to another and let automapper build up the second type.  Trying to use automapper to map two created objects seems strange, but I am not AutoMapper master I know enough to be dangerous.

Comment: Voted down for recommending using automapping to transfer state from DTOs/ViewModels to your domain/business objects.   Modifying the state of your business or domain should be considered a sacrosanct act and not automated by some tool for the sake of saving 30 seconds  of left to right code.

Comment: @Jfar, I am not recommending to use Automapper to take the *easy* way out when mapping domain to viewmodel, dto.  If the classes are similar and you do it often using automapper to define a `CreateMap` that produces the same result each time seems like a nice added benefit.  There are times when automapper is not the right tool for the job and writing left to right code is needed, I was just making the OP aware that there could be a tool useful to assist in his project.  Where he could weigh the pros/cons and decided if it fits the needs in his project.

Comment: @Mark - " am not recommending to use Automapper to take the easy way out when mapping domain to viewmodel" - what? ->
"To assist in this mapping from ViewModel to GranteApplication you can look into using AutoMapper as it might reduce the amount of mapping code."

Comment: @jfar - this is what AutoMapper is for and it does a great job at it.

Comment: I think you shouldn't even have "SelectList" in your viewmodel, you should have at most the selectable items, and then bind them to SOME control in the view, what could be a select list, or radio button, or what's more, even a hotkey based console application selection. So I think changing the GUI control type shouldn't even effect the view model.