# What is the correct way for ASP.NET MVC 3 solution structure, data reference & Automapper integration?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, automapper, n-tier-architecture

I've created an ASP.NET MVC 3 solution. It consists of three separate projects. I'm going to use Automapper and Unity. Each View has its own ViewModel.

The projects are:

- DATA (Code First Models and repository classes are located in this project)
- BUSINESS (Service classes are located in this project. DATA project is added as a reference.)
- WEB (WEB UI project. This is the MVC project. BUSINESS project is added as a reference.)

Now, I have 2 questions.

1. Is this project structure a good practice?
2. I'm trying to use Automapper with my service calls in the controllers. However If I use Automapper in the controller, I have to add DATA project as a reference in my WEB project in order to make conversions from POCOs to ViewModels. Shouldn't the WEB project only interact with BUSINESS project?

Need assistance.

Thank you.

Comment: Darin Dimitrov has an interesting sample project here that is worth a review: https://github.com/darind/samplemvc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Question 1** This is subjective and this isn't the best place to ask it.  However for what it worth, the projects I maintain typically have a Core, Web, and Services project in them.

**Question 2** No, based on your example and my experience, it is fine for your Web project to have references to your DATA and BUSINESS project.  For us, our Web projects know about our Core and Services projects.  However, our Services project does not have a reference to our Web project.  For this reason, our Automapper configuration does know how to map to and from Service Models, View Models, and Entity Models.

Does this help?  Let me know in the comments if you like me to elaborate.  A little ways down [on this blog](http://hendryluk.wordpress.com/tag/domain-driven-design/) you may find an image that depicts a similar project setup to what we use.

Answer (score 0):

What you describe is the usual approach and there's nothing wrong with it in general. There certainly may be approaches that can be considered an alternative. But that depends on your actual requirements and is subject to personal preference as well.

Your POCOs basically are your business objects. And even if they reside in the DATA project, they're part of your domain. It often is better to just put a reference to DATA in your UI project until a more complex solution is required.

Answer (score 0):

I know you already accepted shanabus' answer but I would like to add something to the discussion that may be helpful as well about the second question.

MVC really is a presentation layer architectural pattern and that can lead to a different way to structure your project: 
the presentation layer (your WEB project) should only speak in terms of View Model objects, because it's what really matters to it. Therefore your Business project (or Service Layer) should be in charge of translating from Model to ViewModel and viceversa, using AutoMapper for example, having a reference to the Model and the Repository layer (your Data project in this case).
Given that the Presentation layer is not anymore in charge of translating from Model to ViewModel and viceversa, you can remove the reference to the Data project and solve your problem.

You can find a much better and more detailed explanation at the following link: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/hh456393.aspx

Hope this helps

Comment: Well, according to the below mentioned post, I should use the viewmodels only in controller, not in somewhere else like service layer. Please have a look:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5610887/where-is-best-practice-to-do-mappings-from-view-model-to-domain-model

Comment: There says:

"You should not place any of your mapping logic inside the service layer since it simply dosent belong there. The mapping logic should go inside your controller and nowhere else.

Why you might ask? Simple enough, by placing the mapping logic in your service layer, it needs to know about the ViewModels which the service layer NEVER EVER should be aware of - also it reduces the flexibility of the app that you place the mapping logic in there since you cant reuse the service layer without a lot of hacks."

Comment: I see your point SherleyDev. I don't think there exists THE right answer to this kind of problems: I just wanted to give you a different perspective and opinion on the subject, especially I wanted to provide a solution that helped you to get rid of any reference from the Presentation to the Model.